# What is the difference between Run all at once and Run in sequence,when create a Cognos JOB?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

What is the difference between
**Run all at once**  and  **Run in sequence modes**?
If jobs fail both in those two modes, what will happen? (the scheduled report email will be sent or not?)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFqLy.png)

Comment: I beleive "Run all at once" means they will all run un parallel. Run in sequence pribably enables the "Continue on error" toggle. If that's enabled, jobs will run in sequence. If one fails the other ones will still run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your job has 10 reports in it.

In sequence mode, the first report will run. When it's done, the second will run. Then the 3rd, etc.

In "all at once" mode, the job doesn't wait for anything to finish. All reports are submitted at once and begin running.

Provided the server has the appropriate resources to do so, running the job all at once will complete everything sooner, but it does put a much larger strain on the system. I have jobs where running in sequence ends up being faster because running them all at once is such a bottleneck that it slows down everything to a crawl.

Failure depends on what you select: In either case you can have the job stop if any component fails, or continue running on the other reports if one fails. However, if any component fails then when you view the job status in you schedule list will still show the overall status of the job as "Failed", and "run history details" will show you exactly where the failure was.

Comment: NICE  ANSWER !!   Thanks a lot.